# Why my function declared in requirejs is not collable

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Bellow, my example and it works fine, I mean when I refresh my page, I get output printed to the console `Hi f1.` and `Hi f2.` respectively, but, the thing that I'm not understanding is: when I try for example to execute this function `f1()` in browser console, I can't, I tried `f1()`, `module.f1()` he told me `function undefined` while at the beginning all the functions were well loaded.

Do you know why and what to do to make it callable?

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            module: 'Vendor_module/js/go',
        }
    }
};
```

**go.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($, doc) {
    'use strict';

    function f1() {
        console.log('Hi f1.');
    }

    function f2() {
        console.log('Hi f2.');
    }


    return {
        f1: f1,
        f2: f2
    }
});
```

**file.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'domReady!', 'module'], function($, doc, module) {
    'use strict';

    module.f1(); //output well Hi f1.
    module.f2(); // output well Hi f2.
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you put down your `html` file in detail as its not clear

Comment: The `module.f1()` is within a require context and is passed to the callback. Are you tunning a require when you run this code on the console?

Comment: @korefn no, i turned anything, i tried it directly after loading my page `file.html`

Comment: On the console, you can run `require(['jquery', 'domReady!', 'module'], function($, doc, module) {
    'use strict';

    module.f1(); //output well Hi f1.
    module.f2(); // output well Hi f2.
});` to test.

Comment: @swetansh kumar in `file.html` i haven't a big code, just simple div, then my script `require(...`

Comment: You are requiring it using `requirejs` and it only exists in that context.

Comment: @korefn humm, ok i understand but it will annoy me to do this, I want that my functions to be present as if I declared them directly in a file js, there is no other way to do them available ? i mean call them directly without the `require...`

Comment: On the HTML you can do script tags pointing to the `go.js` file directly. Also, you have to consult the docs for exporting functions in javascript.